# error: require(): Failed opening required file

Tags: php

i am getting the following errors when i am trying to include a file.. i have tried `chmod 777` for the directory..checked twice ,the path is correct ..but still the errors persist
the errors are:

```
Warning: require(../lib/GoogleChart.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project1/admin/googlechart/examples/line_chart_full.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../lib/GoogleChart.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project1/admin/googlechart/examples/line_chart_full.php on line 3
```

What might be wrong is it with the permission cause i have done `chmod -R 777` on the directory

Comment: And is the file in the right place? `chmod` is to change the permissions of a file.

Comment: Why the negative vote beacuse i have read all the solutions given on stackexchange but still the problem persists

Comment: Doing `chmod -R 777` is not going to solve this problem; in fact, it might have made it worse. Where is the file located?

Comment: @ChrisCooney yes it is if i directly run the file on my browser it works fine

Comment: Is the filename ecsacly named GoogleChart.php. If you using lunux, the filesystem is case sensitive.

Comment: @bksi yes it correct .. moreover i am getting this error in a file line_chart_full.php ,it runs perfect when i run directly on a web browser... but when i use `require_once('line_full_chart.php')` it gives the above error

Comment: update the post and show all your full pathes (executed script, requested library folder).

Comment: Does `/opt/lampp/htdocs/project1/admin/googlechart/lib/` folder exist?

Answer (score 0):

You coul try with absolute path starting from documen root (if you have no needs to run the script in command line because $_SERVER array is not provided if the script is launched by a shell)

```
 require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/lib/GoogleChart.php";
```

Giving that the *lib* directory is in the root (www.example.com/lib/GoogleChart.php).

I would suggest **require_once** instead